# How to properly update MySQL data from PHP file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I'd like to update a field in my database using PHP. I wrote this code and works fine. The value of `var2` is 0, after the update its value is 1.
I'd like to use the field `var2` as a PHP variable, thus I can use it as an if condition.
With the if conditional I want to update `var2` if its value is `0`, and redirect to other php file if `var2`'s value is `1`.

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("database",$con);
$sql = "SET SQL_MODE = ''";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
$sql = "UPDATE table SET var2=1 WHERE var1 =    '".$_SESSION['user']."'";

if (){}


mysql_query($sql,$con);
if(mysql_error() != ""){
    echo $sql." ".mysql_error();
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I have tried with

```
$abc = $_POST['var2'];
$sql = "UPDATE table SET "$abc"=1 WHERE var1 =    '".$_SESSION['user']."'";
```

but it doesn't work for me, I got the next message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\egresadoslunes\finalizar.php on line 10"

Comment: First you [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html). You're trying to execute the query before you actually write the query. You have an empty `if` statement.

Comment: What are your doing with `if(){}`?

Comment: check your quoting method, plus what's this supposed to do `$sql = "SET SQL_MODE = ''";` and `if (){}` that does nothing; remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just put a variable after a string literal. You should either explicitly concat it with the `.` operator:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET " . $abc . "=1 WHERE var1 = '".$_SESSION['user']."'";
```

Or have it inline in the string:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET ${abc}=1 WHERE var1 = '".$_SESSION['user']."'";
```

Obligatory comment:
Using such string manipulation techniques leaves your code wide open to sql-injection attacks. You should probably consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: This presumes `$abc` is not a reserved word or something malicious. It really needs to be white-listed against known-good column names and possibly escaped with back-ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if row was affected.

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET var2=1 WHERE var2=0 and  var1 =    '".$_SESSION['user']."'";
$result=(mysql_query);
if( mssql_rows_affected($result) > 0){
     //var 2 == 0
}
else{
     //var 2 != 0
}
```